# Lua pattern matching for empty string

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

after trying and reading Lua's doc on patterns, I couldn't figure it out.

I am using an OBS plugin to activate a source on text document change, and the plugin uses Lua pattern matching. I would like to trigger the source whenver the document is EMPTY and only empty. How can I go about doing this?

Example, using the non-empty pattern match:

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching an empty string is

```
^$
```

where

- `^` - matches the start of string position
- `$` - matches the end of string position.

That is, start and end of string positions must be the same position in the string.

Comment: Or simply `s == ""`.

Comment: @lhf I understand there is no actual code access from the plugin, only a field that accepts a pattern string.